# Excel, Removing a formula after the calculation is completed

Tags: excel-formula

I need a way (that isn't copy paste special) that will remove a formula once it provides an answer. The command F2 then F9 is perfect but i can't work out a way to apply that to 1m rows.

Is there any command in the formula that i can insert that will strip the formula out and simply leave the result onces its calculated.

Copying and pasting special is really slow, cumbersome and error prone when you're dealing with very large workbooks (multiple sheets, 1m plus rows etc).

Comment: Are you open to a solution with macros through VBA?

Comment: Sure, not gonna be a /r/choosingbeggars